# Report difference/change in values between two dataFrames of identical shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

The context is I want to compare two df's and find the difference.

Here's df and df2 with a small difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3),
                   'b': range(3)})

df2 = df.copy()
df2.iloc[1,1] = 100
```

Comparing them yields a 2D boolean df of the same shape:

```
df != df2
Out[28]: 
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
```

I tried to extract the elements corresponding to the True's, but other elements (that I don't want) still occurs as NaN

```
df[df != df2]
Out[29]: 
    a    b
0 NaN  NaN
1 NaN  1.0
2 NaN  NaN
```

How to extract only the elements corresponding to the True's and the indices (so I know where in the df):

```
df[df != df2] # somehow?
Out[30]: 
    b
1 1.0
```

---

update: the above example has only one True. In a general situation with multiple True's, I think are two cases:

1. df is small and one may want to see:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3),
                      'b': range(3)})

   df2 = df.copy()
   df2.iloc[0,0] = 100
   df2.iloc[1,1] = 100

   df[df!=df2].dropna(how='all',axis=(0,1)) # U9-Forward's answer
   Out[39]: 
        a    b
   0  0.0  NaN
   1  NaN  1.0
   ```
2. df is large and one may want to see:

   ```
   index    column   df_value     df2_value
       0         a        0.0           100
       1         b        1.0           100
   ```

@U9-Forward's answer works nicely for case 1, and when there's only one True.

@coldspeed provided a comprehensive solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please take a look at the follow up question posted in my answer and let us know what is the output you are looking for in the general case?

Comment: @coldspeed thank you for bringing up the general case and for the comprehensive solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask on the values:

```
df.values[df != df2]
# array([1])
```

---

How should this case be handled?

```
df2.at[0, 'a'] = 100

df
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2

df2
     a    b
0  100    0
1    1  100
2    2    2

df != df2 
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False   True
2  False  False

df.values[df != df2]
# array([0, 1])

# in the other answer
df[df!=df2].dropna(how='all',axis=(0,1))
     a    b
0  0.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0
```

Which is the required output?

---

If you just the values in each column of `df` that differ, something simple like `agg` and `dropna` will do.

```
df[df != df2].agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())

a    [0.0]
b    [1.0]
dtype: object
```

---

If you want the indices and columns, use `melt`:

```
u = df2.reset_index().melt('index')
v = df.reset_index().melt('index')

u[u['value'] != v['value']]
   index variable  value
0      0        a    100
4      1        b    100
```

---

Or, use `np.nonzero`, to do this with numpy - True values are nonzero, the indices of these are returned.

```
m = (df != df2).values
idx, cols = np.nonzero(m)

pd.DataFrame({
    'index': df.index.values[idx],
    'column': df.columns.values[cols],
    'value_1': df.values[m],
    'value_2': df2.values[m]
})

   index column  value_1  value_2
0      0      a        0      100
1      1      b        1      100
```

Answer (score 2):

Use condition and then `dropna`:

```
print(df[df!=df2].dropna(how='all',axis=(0,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If want information about index and columns add [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3),
                   'b': range(3)})

df2 = df.copy()
df2.iloc[1,1] = 100
df2.iloc[0,0] = 100

s = df.stack()
s2 = df2.stack()
out = s[s != s2].rename_axis(['idx','col']).reset_index(name='val')
print (out)
   idx col  val
0    0   a    0
1    1   b    1

out2 = s2[s != s2].rename_axis(['idx','col']).reset_index(name='val')
print (out2)
   idx col  val
0    0   a  100
1    1   b  100
```

Or use `numpy indexing` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for indices of `True`s values:

```
mask = df != df2
a = np.where(mask)

out = pd.DataFrame({'idx': df.index.values[a[0]],
                    'cols': df.columns.values[a[1]],
                    'vals_df': df.values[mask],
                    'vals_df2': df2.values[mask]})
print (out)
   idx cols  vals_df  vals_df2
0    0    a        0       100
1    1    b        1       100
```

Answer (score 1):

A numpy solution:

```
mask = df2[df!=df2]
a = mask.values
```

This returns an array.

```
x = a[~np.isnan(a)].astype(int)
>>x
array([100])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and then filter for for value that are different:

```
diffs = df.ne(df2).reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])
>>> diffs[diffs['value'].eq(True)].iloc[:, :-1].reset_index(drop=True)
   index variable
0      1        b
```